# com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException:Compilation failed to complete, position:Lcom/facebook/login/DefaultAudience$EnumUnboxingLocalUtility;

Tags: android, facebook, gradle, proguard, android-r8

I have some error, after updated kotlin version (**ext.kotlin_version**) to **1.6.10**:

```
com.android.tools.r8.internal.E00: Unexpected type in conversion to primitive: OBJECT

Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
> com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, position: Lcom/facebook/login/DefaultAudience$EnumUnboxingLocalUtility;getNativeProtocolAudience(I)Ljava/lang/String;, origin: ..\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\57102c4e3d32396b86898e5ca0dd620d\transformed\jetified-facebook-core-7.1.0-runtime.jar:com/facebook/login/DefaultAudience.class
```

It happened, if I use options **minifyEnabled true** in my **build.gradle**(:app) with **Generate signed bundle**.
If I use old **ext.kotlin_version** (for examle, 1.5.0) this error did not appear.

I think, if I use correct rule(s) in **proguard-rules.pro** I could resolve this issue.

Answer (score 13):

This was caused by an [issue in R8](https://issuetracker.google.com/218400336). Fix is available in R8 3.1.71, 3.2.55 and 3.3.26-dev versions.

Add the following to `settings.gradle` or `settings.gradle.kts` to use a specific version of R8 different from the one bundeled with AGP:

```
pluginManagement {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven {
                url = uri("https://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw")
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath("com.android.tools:r8:X.Y.Z")
            classpath('com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre')  // <-- THIS IS REQUIRED UNTIL R8 3.2.4-dev
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this works perfectly in my react native project

Comment: I got this error `settings file '/Users/abc/Documents/Work/VedaxLink/android/settings.gradle': 2: The pluginManagement {} block must appear before any other statements in the script.`, can someone help?

Comment: lol worked to me

Answer (score 4):

In my case i just changed minSdkVersion from 23 to 27 in app.gradle file it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I find right rule for decide this problem.
You need add this code into **proguard-rules.pro**:

```
-keep class com.facebook.login.** {*;}
```

This line let ignore option **minifyEnabled true** for all files into **com.facebook.login** package.

Comment: With the compiler fix in R8 there should be no need for keeping the `com.facebook.login` package. If new issues arise please file a bug on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788 for further analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Just changed minSdkVersion 24 in app.gradle

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).